# Regex to include quotes in match between quotes (and new lines)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find strings enclosed in single quotes with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dblbsl/2) : `/'+(.*?)'+,?/g`

The problem is that single quotes are allowed inside the string as long as they are escaped with a second quote: `'it''s, you''ve, I''m... and so on, ends with one more single quote '''`.

My regex breaks if there are any amount of single quotes inside and ends up skipping quotes in the beginning and end of the match if there are any.

It seems to work perfectly as long as nobody adds any quotes inside the string. But this is not how the real world works unfortunately.

How can I make my regex include the quotes in the match?

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are correct in the string you pasted to regex101? You should be able to match correctly with `'([^']*(?:''[^']*)*)',?` - but your sample seems broken to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex:

```
'(?:''|[^'])*'
```

explanation: single quote followd by (two quotes OR a non quote char) repeated as necessary, followed by a closing single quote.

https://regex101.com/r/R4sd47/1

Comment: this not recognize 2 matches in this setence:
'''''Plan'''''Design'

Comment: there's only  one match in that sequence as far as i can see: `'''''Plan'''''`

Comment: My bad on that one. There should only be two single quotes to escape into one quote. That line has one quote too many, after Plan. https://regex101.com/r/dblbsl/2. But your regex does not work for the rest of the text if you try it on my example text.

Comment: @mottosson, can you, please, show us the exact text that we need to apply regex? can we cut '''''Plan'''''Design' ?

Comment: I've modified the regex to include empty strings `''` and use your input text block, it appears to parse them correctly.